# Will a full install of Ubuntu 18.10 on a usb key affect the hard drive of the machines i will plug it in?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, uefi

As per title i have installed Ubuntu 18.10 (and the grub bootloader) on a usb key that i can but in uefi mode from any computer.

My question is if i run any command from the terminal (mainly apt) will that affect in any way the hdd of the machine i'm working on or i will be totally safe and ubuntu will only work on his usb key for updates and such?

Comment: Depends on the commands in question. Some commands may be used to modify files on the HDD, so it is really up to the user behind the keyboard.

Comment: **Any command** is too broad. In particular you can type one command. The command will format the internal hard drive. Or two commands can mount the main partition and delete all it's contents. In all these commands you will have to specify the drive or partition you want to destroy.

Comment: You can set up a guest user that is unable to modify any drives on the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During installation, you may affect the internal drive, but now that you have the drive, **it will not tamper with the internal drive by itself**. I have made and used several such systems (with various versions of Ubuntu), and I am confident, that it behaves well.

But if you tell your Ubuntu to write a file to a file system in the internal drive, it will do it (if the permissions permit writing). And if you tell your Ubuntu to edit the partition table (for example to remove a partition), it will do it.

---

Edit: `apt` will only write into the own system. It will not tamper with your internal drive. `update-grub` will only write into the own system. but it will probably find the operating system in your internal drive and add a line for it to your grub menu.

---

There is one exception: If you created your Ubuntu 18.10 (and the grub bootloader) on a USB key by **cloning** your internal Ubuntu system, the drives will be identical, with identical UUIDs and then, when you boot, there will probably be confusion, and one or both systems might be damaged.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! 
I guess i'm all good because the drive was created with a new install using a sistem with no hdd just a live usb and my target usb and I wont ever mess with the internal hdd trough Ubuntu.

Thanks again!

Comment: @lukaarma, Yes, you're all good with your USB drive with Ubuntu. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Add a Guest User to Ubuntu 18.04

You can set up a guest user account that is unable to modify any drives on the computer.

Ubuntu 18.04 does not come with a guest user account as previous versions did, but you can add one:

- Install **lightdm**:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install lightdm
  ```
- At popup select lightdm as display manager.
- After install run:

  ```
  sudo gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-guest.conf
  ```
- Change: `allow-guest=true`.
- Starting next boot there will be a guest user, no changes will be saved during a guest session.
- The administrator may change settings and add programs, See: [Customize Guest Session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession)