# Non-persistent Ubuntu 18.04 install?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, reboot, persistence

How can I install a non-persistent version of Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer (not a live usb), so when I reboot my computer it would be like a fresh install (minus the installation wizard)?
Thanks

Comment: well why exactly is it that the USB wouldn't fulfill this pupose adequately? keep in mind the non persistent version is incredibly limitted in what it can install and do. most likely what you intend to do with it won't be allowed/work...

Comment: @tatsu A bootable USB 'works', but is slow and doesn't seem to fully utilize the hardware. I would want to modify an ISO with a few common programs that wipes on reboot, not too dissimilar to how a university/school login would work.

Comment: well you don't want a non-persistant ubuntu then, you just want to add "wipe at reboot" functionality to a regular install of ubuntu after you've done first updates, installed drivers and all the apps you need. Because with a non-persistent, you wouldn't be able to utilize the hardware and plenty of other issues you have on the live stick.

Comment: How about guest mode? It rewipes on reboot

Comment: @Parto Yes, I guess I want a wipe-on-reboot system. Is there automatic functionality for this? I guess a bash script could accomplish this...Guest mode sounds great then, I'll take a look, thanks!

Comment: You can install a live Ubuntu system into a hard disk drive or an SSD with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). You can make it live-only or persistent live. In both cases it will be fast (because the hard disk drive or SSD is much faster than a USB pendrive). -- You can also use guest mode, but it is no longer provided in the newest versions of Ubuntu, because there are security holes. But I think it is at least as secure as a persistent live system. A live-only system will be clean after reboot, which is a good (and easy) alternative.

Comment: You can create a guest account that will reset every boot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126997/will-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-18-10-on-a-usb-key-affect-the-hard-drive-of-the-ma/1127106#1127106

Comment: You can install the installation .ISO to a directory on your hard drive and then have grub boot to it: https://www.howtogeek.com/196933/how-to-boot-linux-iso-images-directly-from-your-hard-drive/